# Region Conflict VPN in GCP?

Tags: vpn, google-cloud-vpn

I've beem having a problem in GCP.

[I have two vpns, each one with two tunnels.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aC07R.png)

VPN 1 is in region us-east.
VPN 2 is in region us-central.

The problem:
When i try to connect to my DB using a vm instance that is created in us-central, i can only connect through the VPN 2. When i use the VPN 1 with this VM, i can not connect to my DB.

The same happens when my VM is us-east, i can only connect to my DB via VPN 1.

Is this a problem that happens? Or just coincidence?

**EDIT:**

I think i found out the problem. 
The vpn 1 and vpn 2 is configured with different sub networks.

**VPN 1:** *10.142.0.0/20*

**VPN 2:** *10.128.0.0/20*

All VMs with in us-central are 10.128.0.0/20
All VMs in us-east are 10.142.0.0/20

[See the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRZaQ.jpg)

Comment: There is a routing issue. Can you show your routing table on GCP?

Comment: [Route Table](https://imgur.com/a/QQ2XVIJ).

I'm thinking about inserting a network tag to the route and the VMs.

VMs in us-central will have the tag 'us-central'.
VMs in us-east will have the tag 'us-east'.

And the routes will do the same.

Comment: Great you found a solution :) If you think my reply was useful then please accept it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you have to closely examine [your routing](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/) and [firewall rules](https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/firewalls/). Though at the first sight I don't see anything else in the routing table you might as well be missing something.

I'm guessing that `10.0.0.0/8` network is the one where your DB is (outside GCP).
You might try adding the route to it to the VPN1 (both tunnels) and see if it helps.

I also assume that all your VM's are in the `default` VPC so they can "talk" to each other and all of them can ping both VPN gateways (as described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/overview#ha-vpn)). Check if your [VPN routing options](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/choosing-networks-routing#routing-options) are in order.

If after adding/changing the routes it still won't work try to trace the actual route and post the results.